# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'. Can't get PyGObject installed

Tags: python, linux, pygobject, modulenotfounderror

I've been trying to solve this issue for about a week or two now, still haven't found a solution. I'm on Arch Linux. Here's what I've tried so far:

- installed python-gobject and gobject-introspection through pacman
- installed pycairo through python
- Tried installing PyGObject through python, but it's throwing an error
- tried pip install PyGObject --no-use-pep517
- pip install --upgrade wheel
- Reset $PATH variable

I do have Anaconda installed, which has been mentioned in other forums with similar issues, but haven't figured out what the problem could be regarding conda.

The main problem is I can't get PyGObject installed.

Here's the output for the program I'm trying to run:

```
$ ./lutris
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/greyside/git/lutris/bin/./lutris", line 52, in <module>
    from lutris.gui.application import Application  # pylint: disable=no-name-in-module
  File "/home/greyside/git/lutris/lutris/gui/application.py", line 28, in <module>
    import gi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

Here's the output for pip install PyGObject:

```
$ pip install PyGObject
Collecting PyGObject
  Using cached PyGObject-3.42.0.tar.gz (716 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pycairo>=1.16.0 in /home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from PyGObject) (1.21.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyGObject
  Building wheel for PyGObject (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/greyside/anaconda3/bin/python /home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpn15zx71v
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-s12pfc6q/pygobject_15ec34742d654e599404ba75c60a660e
  Complete output (98 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/pygtkcompat
  copying pygtkcompat/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/pygtkcompat
  copying pygtkcompat/generictreemodel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/pygtkcompat
  copying pygtkcompat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/pygtkcompat
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/module.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/importer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/docstring.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/_signalhelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/_propertyhelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/_ossighelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/_option.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/_gtktemplate.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/_error.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/repository
  copying gi/repository/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/repository
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/keysyms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/Pango.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/Gtk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/Gio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/GdkPixbuf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/Gdk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/GObject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/GLib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/GIMarshallingTests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  running build_ext
  pycairo: new API
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 349, in <module>
      main()
    File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 331, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 248, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 244, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 229, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 281, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 174, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 1259, in <module>
      main()
    File "setup.py", line 1219, in main
      setup(
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 87, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 163, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "setup.py", line 1088, in run
      self._setup_extensions()
    File "setup.py", line 1083, in _setup_extensions
      add_pycairo(gi_cairo_ext)
    File "setup.py", line 1066, in add_pycairo
      ext.include_dirs += [get_pycairo_include_dir()]
    File "setup.py", line 893, in get_pycairo_include_dir
      include_dir = find_path(find_new_api())
    File "setup.py", line 848, in find_new_api
      import cairo
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cairo/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
      from ._cairo import *  # noqa: F401,F403
  ImportError: /tmp/pip-build-env-4lzlmpry/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: cairo_tee_surface_index
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyGObject
Failed to build PyGObject
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyGObject which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

And here's the output for pip install PyGObject --no-use-pep517:

```
pip install PyGObject --no-use-pep517
Collecting PyGObject
  Using cached PyGObject-3.42.0.tar.gz (716 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pycairo>=1.16.0 in /home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from PyGObject) (1.21.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: PyGObject
  Building wheel for PyGObject (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/greyside/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-72srifkn
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/
  Complete output (85 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/pygtkcompat
  copying pygtkcompat/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/pygtkcompat
  copying pygtkcompat/generictreemodel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/pygtkcompat
  copying pygtkcompat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/pygtkcompat
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/module.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/importer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/docstring.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/_signalhelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/_propertyhelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/_ossighelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/_option.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/_gtktemplate.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/_error.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  copying gi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/repository
  copying gi/repository/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/repository
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/keysyms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/Pango.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/Gtk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/Gio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/GdkPixbuf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/Gdk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/GObject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/GLib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  copying gi/overrides/GIMarshallingTests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
  running build_ext
  pycairo: new API
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py", line 1259, in <module>
      main()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py", line 1219, in main
      setup(
    File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 87, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 163, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py", line 1088, in run
      self._setup_extensions()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py", line 1083, in _setup_extensions
      add_pycairo(gi_cairo_ext)
    File "/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py", line 1066, in add_pycairo
      ext.include_dirs += [get_pycairo_include_dir()]
    File "/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py", line 893, in get_pycairo_include_dir
      include_dir = find_path(find_new_api())
    File "/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py", line 848, in find_new_api
      import cairo
    File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cairo/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
      from ._cairo import *  # noqa: F401,F403
  ImportError: /home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: cairo_tee_surface_index
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyGObject
  Running setup.py clean for PyGObject
Failed to build PyGObject
Installing collected packages: PyGObject
    Running setup.py install for PyGObject ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/greyside/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-0v4b5sk8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/greyside/anaconda3/include/python3.9/PyGObject
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/
    Complete output (89 lines):
    running install
    /home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
      warnings.warn(
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/pygtkcompat
    copying pygtkcompat/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/pygtkcompat
    copying pygtkcompat/generictreemodel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/pygtkcompat
    copying pygtkcompat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/pygtkcompat
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
    copying gi/types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
    copying gi/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
    copying gi/module.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
    copying gi/importer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
    copying gi/docstring.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
    copying gi/_signalhelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
    copying gi/_propertyhelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
    copying gi/_ossighelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
    copying gi/_option.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
    copying gi/_gtktemplate.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
    copying gi/_error.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
    copying gi/_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
    copying gi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/repository
    copying gi/repository/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/repository
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/keysyms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/Pango.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/Gtk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/Gio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/GdkPixbuf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/Gdk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/GObject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/GLib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
    copying gi/overrides/GIMarshallingTests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/gi/overrides
    running build_ext
    pycairo: new API
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py", line 1259, in <module>
        main()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py", line 1219, in main
        setup(
      File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 87, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        return run_commands(dist)
      File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 163, in run_commands
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
        super().run_command(command)
      File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 68, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/install.py", line 670, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
        super().run_command(command)
      File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1214, in run_command
        super().run_command(command)
      File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py", line 1088, in run
        self._setup_extensions()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py", line 1083, in _setup_extensions
        add_pycairo(gi_cairo_ext)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py", line 1066, in add_pycairo
        ext.include_dirs += [get_pycairo_include_dir()]
      File "/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py", line 893, in get_pycairo_include_dir
        include_dir = find_path(find_new_api())
      File "/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py", line 848, in find_new_api
        import cairo
      File "/home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cairo/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from ._cairo import *  # noqa: F401,F403
    ImportError: /home/greyside/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: cairo_tee_surface_index
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/greyside/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-yujdqs8g/pygobject_33b98e7ae1f94d9ea4537c84d96133cb/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-0v4b5sk8/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/greyside/anaconda3/include/python3.9/PyGObject Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: What's your pycairo and libcairo version (in conda)?

Comment: @SuperStormer pycairo: 1.21.0, libcairo isn't showing up in pip_search, but under pacman I have cairomm (1.14.3-2) and cairomm-1.16 (1.16.1-2). I'm guessing not being able to find libcairo in conda could be the problem? conda install libcairo says "PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - libcairo

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
"